# Can I override nested object styles in Material UI when applying custom theme?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I created my custom theme, and I'm trying to style the `Tabs` and `Tab` Material UI component. But the Tab Component is a `ButtonBase`, and as I don't want all buttons to be overriden, I tried to override nested object styles like this:

```
MuiTabs: {
    root: {
        // Section being applied correctly
        borderRadius: 3,
        padding: 0,
        minHeight: 32,
        backgroundColor: theme.button.backgroundDisabled,

        // NOT being applied
        MuiButtonBase: {
            root: {
                backgroundColor: 'red',
            },
        },
    },
}
```

the `MuiButtonBase-root` style is not being applied. Can I do that without using string styles like this?

```
MuiTabs: {
    root: {
        ....                 
        // This IS being applied.
        '& .MuiButtonBase-root': {
             backgroundColor: 'red',
        },
    },
}
```

Is there any way to apply the first approach and not string styling?

Comment: What's the problem with the second approach?

Comment: @NearHuscarl None, just curious and asking if this is possible.

Comment: The closest you can do if you don't want nested css selector is to override the default props [`classes`](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#overriding-styles-classes-prop), but the [`Tabs`](https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/#css) component doesn't expose the tabButton ruleName to override so in your case, the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the tab button, you will see a list of classes that look like this:

```
MuiButtonBase-root MuiTab-root MuiTab-textColorInherit
```

The `BaseButton` to switch between `Tab`s is also called `MuiTab`, you can target this component and override its styles directly like below:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTab: {
      root: {
        backgroundColor: "pink"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67174061/can-i-override-nested-object-styles-in-material-ui-when-applying-custom-theme]

Comment: Touché! I didn't see it was a singular `MuiTab` and not `MuiTabs`.... Thanksss

Comment: But that doesn't solve my question already.. how can I nest it?

Comment: @Sonhja I don't think you can do that without using css selector. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67174061/can-i-override-nested-object-styles-in-material-ui-when-applying-custom-theme/67174956?noredirect=1#comment118737796_67174061) comment. I've looked at the type [definition](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/1617f4ee72920d40d0b0f9dac34f90b82dadf4bf/packages/material-ui/src/styles/overrides.d.ts#L212) to confirm it. My answer can only help you in this specific case where you want to style `MuiTab`. Sorry